# Show: scaling transformation $Y_i=D^{-1}(X_i-\bar{X})$ can be written as $Y = HX_{n\times p}D^{-1}$

Tags: self-study, multivariate-analysis, data-transformation, centering

Show that the scaling transformation $\textbf{y}_i=D^{-1}(\textbf{x}_i-\bar{\textbf{x}})$ can be written as $Y = HX_{n\times p}D^{-1}$ where $H$ is the centering matrix $(I_n-\frac{1}{n}\textbf{11}')$.

I know that $HX=\pmatrix{\textbf{x}'_1-\bar{\textbf{x}}'\\\vdots\\\textbf{x}'_n-\bar{\textbf{x}}'}$. Using this I can write $Y=\pmatrix{(\textbf{x}_1'-\bar{\textbf{x}}')D^{-1}\\\vdots\\(\textbf{x}_n'-\bar{\textbf{x}}')D^{-1}}$.

However, the hint says: use $Y'HY=D^{-1}X'HXD^{-1}$. Not really sure how I can show the equivalence of the definitions using this facr. Hints would be great!

[This is an exercise from Mardia, Kent, Bibbi]

Comment: Please use the "self-study" tag. Reading at the exercise 1.5.2,  I do not see the hint you report. Mind the lower case convention used for vectors in the book. If a relation $\mathbf{v}_i = \mathbf{A} \mathbf{v}_i$ holds for $n$ couples of vectors $\mathbf{u}_i$ and $\mathbf{v}_i$ how  are related the matrices $\mathbf{U}$ and $\mathbf{V}$ having the (transposed) vectors as theirs rows?

Comment: @Yves Not sure I get your question? $\textbf{y_i}$ is a $p\times1$ vector. Consequently, we expect $Y$ to be an $n \times p$ vector with $n$ rows of $1\times p$ vectors.

Comment: Sorry for the typo I meant $\mathbf{v}_i = \mathbf{A} \mathbf{u}_i$. Yes $\mathbf{y}_i$ is a vector with length $p$ and so is $\mathbf{x}_i$ while $X$ and $Y$ are *matrices*. The linear relations between the $n$ vectors $\mathbf{y}_i$ and $\mathbf{x}_i$ can be written as a relation between the matrices $X$ and $Y$. Just make a drawing of the matrices as rectangles with their rows stacked inside (and forget the "hint").

Comment: Aha. Get it! Got distracted by the hint.